# How to set the world spawn to a player?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am making a minigame in minecraft, and would like to know if there is a way to set a world spawn to a player, so that the compass points to them.

Answer (score 1):

In a repeating command block, use the command:

```
execute at <player identifier> setworldspawn ~ ~ ~
```

Comment: This don't work because you are missing run between <player identifier> and setworldspawn

Answer (score 0):

try `/execute at <player> run setworldspawn ~ ~ ~`

Answer (score 0):

`/execute at <player> run setworldspawn ~ ~ ~`